# GroupBy + OrderByDescending, returning separate id

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a query that I just can't get Entity Framework Core 3 (and 5, tried both) to translate.

What I want to do, is to group by a certain id, fetch the latest entry for said id, and return another id. In reality, I want to fetch the the id of the latest chat message for an arbitrary amount of chat rooms.

So with the following class:

```
class ChatMessageEntry
{
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid ChatRoomId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }

        // message etc here...
}
```

, given a list of ChatRoomIds, I want to retrieve the Id of the last entry  (CreatedAtUtc) per ChatRoomId.

What I have tried (chatRoomIds is a list of Guids, corresponding to ChatMessageEntry.ChatRoomId):

```
            var lastChatMessagePerChat = await this.chatContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => chatRoomIds.Contains(t.ChatRoomId) && !t.DeletedAtUtc.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(t => t.ChatRoomId)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedAtUtc).First())
                .ToListAsync()
```

...throws...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: new { 
    Id = c.Id, 
    ChatRoomId = c.ChatRoomId, 
    CreatedAtUtc = c.CreatedAtUtc
 }, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: ChatMessageEntry
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedAtUtc)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

When I read up on the GroupBy operations in Entity Framework, I understood that only operations such as Count and Max work. So I rewrote it as such:

```
            var lastChatMessageIdPerChat = await this.chatContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => chatRoomIds.Contains(t.ChatRoomId) && !t.DeletedAtUtc.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(t => t.ChatRoomId)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Id = g.Select(t => t.Id),
                    CreatedAtUtc = g.Max(t => t.CreatedAtUtc),
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

...which in turn throws...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: c.ChatRoomId, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: ChatMessageEntry
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .Select(s => s.Id)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

...because I'm still using g.Select inside the group. I could retrieve ChatRoomId instead:

```
            var lastChatMessageIdPerChat = await this.chatContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(t => chatRoomIds.Contains(t.ChatRoomId) && !t.DeletedAtUtc.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(t => t.ChatRoomId)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    ChatRoomId = g.Key,
                    CreatedAtUtc = g.Max(t => t.CreatedAtUtc),
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

...which would technically work but I need the latest entry's Id, not its grouping id, so this is useless to me.
If I add another grouping,

```
.GroupBy(t => new { t.ChatRoomId, t.Id })
```

, then I can access the Id but the sort no longer works (the result is as if I didn't group them at all).

Very appreciative of help.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the workaround from the duplicate post (replace `First()` with `Take(1)`). And go vote for [Support ability to select top N of each group #13805](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13805).

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev and thanks for the reply. I had seen the the question you linked to already but unfortunately I am not sure if it will help me. I already have the list of the chat room ids so it boils down to just doing one query per chat room, code which I already have. So should I take it that it is impossible to fetch the newest message per group for N chats without doing N queries? That's quite ineffective, if I'm requesting the latest message for 10 chats I'm doing 10 queries. I was hoping there was a way of doing it in one query but maybe not? Thanks for further insight.

Comment: If you start your LINQ query with in-memory list, it will run in LINQ to Objects (`Enumerable`) context, so yes, it will execute N database queries. But if you use the technique from the "duplicate" link as `GroupBy` replacement (even though you already have these ids), it will be translated and executed as single database query. Basically it will do exactly what if your original LINQ query translation was supported, which is the linked EF Core GitHub feature request.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks so much. I had not understood that nesting it like that executed the query server side, I thought both styles would execute multiple queries. I will try it out, thank you!